# create multiple pages from one page, PHP

Tags: php

I created a webpage in which i am changing string according to URL. For example my page name is 'motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-city.php' then I am showing 'city' in place of city name. if i change my page name to 'motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-italy.php', Then italy will be shown in place of city name.

Now my problem is on index page i want to link this page, With different different city name but i want to open this php page with city name.

Example:-

```
  <a href="motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-washington.php">washington</a>
  <a href="motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-italy.php">italy</a>
  <a href="motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-london.php">london</a>
```

On link click open

```
 motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-city.php
```

Here city name change with  italy or london or washington.

Comment: try with passing argument in url

Comment: no i dont want with parameters. As per my client requirement i want pages like this.

Comment: If you do like this there must have lot of php pages

Comment: May be we can do this .htaccess

Comment: @DhinjuDivakaran  I don't want to do this.  I have more then 500 cities, So it's very difficult to manage 500 static pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your script is named city.php and you're running apache, you can use mod-rewrite.  Try putting this into your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-\w*.php city.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, But as i said i am allready doing that. my problem is how i change file name dynamically.

Comment: Are you storing the city names somewhere? Also what do you mean by changing the file name dynamically?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  So you have a php script that prints the name of the city based on the url, let's call this city.php. Now from the index page or any page, when someone clicks on the link "motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle[*].php".  You want it to go to city.php? Is this correct?

Comment: motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle[*].php, Here * is city name. now when someone click on link then i want to change my city.php name to 'motivational-keynote-speaker-seattle-[cityname].php'

Comment: Sorry can't understand. On linux system ubuntu12.04

Comment: What web server are you using to serve your html and php pages?